# how can I obtain exact values of sin and cos in matlab for angles like pi/4?

Tags: matlab, calculus, inexact-arithmetic

if I write in matlab

```
cos(pi/4)
```

I get this form:

```
0.7071
```

when I'd prefer getting it actual value of (2)^(1/2)/2 to write formulas more clearly.
is there a way to do what I ask?

Comment: Without the Matlab symbolic toolbox then the floating-point number approximated by `0.7071` is as good as you will get -- of course, behind the scenes Matlab is using the full double-precision representation of the number, and by default displaying only the first 4 significant digits.  You're not getting the display format and the internal value mixed up are you ?

Comment: perhaps OP would like to try

    `> format long`

Comment: no I'm not,but since I have the symbolic toolbox I wonder why I get that form instead of a more clear one

Comment: @user3149593: Because it's *considerably* more computationally expensive to evaluate symbolic math expressions in general and thus you have to explicitly use it.

Comment: I don't see why you find `cos(pi/4)` unclear. The result in Matlab is a numerical approximation, sure, after all you are using a programming language specialized for numeric computations. But the *code* in which you write this expression is clear as day, it says exactly what it means.

Comment: @A.Donda I'd kepp     cos(pi/4)  if I could,it's the number that I don't want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can you use the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) that comes with many installs of Matlab:

```
theta = sym(pi)/4;
cos(theta)
```

which returns

```
ans =

2^(1/2)/2
```

Comment: that's really a strange way to solve it,but it works greatly,thanks a lot

Comment: @user3149593 you should be aware that the result is not anymore an integer, double, or .... it is a sym type.

Comment: @NKN doing eval() I can get it back to double if needed righ?

Comment: @user3149593: Not strange at all. Matlab, like most programming languages, uses floating-point representation. This value and many others have no exact form in floating-point. To convert the numerical output of a symbolic calculation back to double precision floating-point, use the `double` function.